# Добавить новое значение в список внутри словаря

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь в котором значение у ключей содержит список. Как я могу добавить новое значение внутрь списка?

```
mydict = {'255_01':[1, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141],'255_02':[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например так - безопасный код, чтобы добавлять значение по ключу, даже если в словаре нет данных с таким ключом

```
mydict = {'255_01':[1, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141],'255_02':[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]}

mydict[key] = mydict.get(key, []) + [value]
```